# form.submit() Takes 40+ seconds to trigger action

Tags: asp.net, performance, vbscript, asp-classic, form-submit

I have a simple page that's used to pass session variables from an old ASP/VBScript page to a newer ASPX/VB page:

### `asptonetconn.asp`

```vb
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
' We grab all the session variable names/values and stick them in a form
' and then we submit the form to our receiving ASP.NET page (ASPNETPage1.aspx)...
Session("DestPage") = "/" & Request.QueryString("dest")

Response.Write("<form name=t id=t action=netfromaspconn.aspx method=post >")

For Each Item In Session.Contents
    Response.Write("<input type=hidden name=" & Item)
    Response.Write( " value=" & Session.Contents(item) & " >")
Next

Response.Write("</form>")
Response.Write("<script>t.submit();</script>")
%>
```

From there, it goes to:

### `netfromaspconn.aspx`

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat=server>
    ' We iterate through the Form collection and assign the names and values
    ' to ASP.NET session variables! We have another Session Variable, "DestPage"
    ' that tells us where to go after taking care of our business...
    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Form.Count - 1
            Session(Request.Form.GetKey(i)) = Request.Form(i).ToString()
        Next
        
        [...other functional code...]
    End Sub
</script>
```

We just recently moved this site to a new server. Before the move, this "hand-off" was virtually instantaneous and the user hardly, if ever, saw anything about either of these files. Now, however, it's taking 40+ seconds each time the navigation has to go through this process (which, unfortunately, is fairly frequently until I have the time to rebuild the "front" pages). Thankfully, it *does* get through and pass everything from one "side" to the other, but I can't figure out what's taking it so long.

When I look at the browser's address bar while I'm waiting, it seems to be hanging on the `asptonetconn.asp` file because, once it navigates to the `netfromaspconn.aspx` page, everything snaps into place and I never actually *see* that page show up. To diagnose the issue, I've sprinkled in some `Response.Write()` statements in the `asptonetconn.asp` file to try and determine what, specifically, is causing the "hang", but they all seem to write to the page immediately. Also, it doesn't seem to matter what value I send to `Request.QueryString("dest")`. It *always* takes around 43 seconds.

Based on all of my testing, it seems like the problem is that last line is just taking forever to `submit()` the form. Since this is the exact same code as was on the other server, I can't imagine why this would be a problem. Could someone help point me in the right direction? It's necessary that these `Session` values are passed from the older page to the newer, but I'm open to other means of achieving that goal.

---

### UPDATE #1

So, I'm doing some more testing to try and find the cause of the slow response during the `submit()` execution. As I work through this, I'll try to consolidate any "additional information" from comments and such here as well to provide a complete picture.

First, based on the comment from @user692942, I went in and "quotified" all of the HTML attribute values. I tried both with double quotes (`""` - doubled up for parsing by the `Response.Write()` method) and single quotes (`'`). This didn't have any impact on the page loading. I had also seen some comment somewhere about fully qualifying the URI for the `action` attribute, so I did that as well without change. Here's what I'm using at present:

```html
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
' We grab all the session variable names/values and stick them in a form
' and then we submit the form to our receiving ASP.NET page (ASPNETPage1.aspx)...
Session("DestPage") = "/" & Request.QueryString("dest")

Response.Write("<form name='t' id='t' action='https://example.com/netfromaspconn.aspx' method='POST'>" & vbcrlf)

For Each Item In Session.Contents
    Response.Write(vbtab & "<input type='hidden' name='" & Item & "' ")
    Response.Write("value='" & Trim(Session.Contents(item)) & "' />" & vbcrlf)
Next

Response.Write("</form>" & vbcrlf)
Response.Write("<script>t.submit();</script>")
%>
```

During the 40+ seconds that the browser was sitting on the `asptonetconn.asp` page, I grabbed the source code from the browser and it looks correct (*cleaned up and truncated for brevity*):

```html
<form name='t' id='t' action='https://example.com/netfromaspconn.aspx' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='Cook' value='COOKIE ISSUED' />
    <input type='hidden' name='browser' value='1' />

    [... other session values ...]

    <input type='hidden' name='MLoc' value='1' />
    <input type='hidden' name='Loc' value='1' />
    <input type='hidden' name='dbNum' value='1' />
    <input type='hidden' name='cookiemessage' value='cookie=nothing' />
    <input type='hidden' name='HTTP_User_Agent' value='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' />
    <input type='hidden' name='securitymsg' value='1' />
    <input type='hidden' name='DestPage' value='Login.aspx?Alpha=0' />
</form>
<script>t.submit();</script>
```

Looking through some of the IIS logs on the server, it seems to me that the issue has to do with "processing" the form's data on the `submit`:

```
2023-07-11 17:26:38 10.X.X.X GET /process.asp - 443 - 174.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/114.0.1823.67 https://example.com/secure.asp 200 0 0 82
2023-07-11 17:26:42 10.X.X.X GET /asptonetconn.asp dest=Login.aspx?Alpha=0 443 - 174.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/114.0.1823.67 https://example.com/process.asp 200 0 0 24
2023-07-11 17:27:25 10.X.X.X POST /netfromaspconn.aspx - 443 - 174.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/114.0.1823.67 https://example.com/asptonetconn.asp?dest=Login.aspx?Alpha=0 302 0 0 42702
2023-07-11 17:27:25 10.X.X.X GET /WebResource.axd d=<data>&t=<data> 443 - 174.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/114.0.1823.67 https://example.com/LoginPortal.aspx?Alpha=0 200 0 0 27
2023-07-11 17:27:25 10.X.X.X GET /LoginPortal.aspx Alpha=0 443 - 174.X.X.X Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/114.0.1823.67 https://example.com/asptonetconn.asp?dest=LoginPortal.aspx?Alpha=0 200 0 0 224
```

I'm not sure why it's taking 42.7 seconds after the browser calls for `asptonetconn.asp` to finally call for `netfromaspconn.aspx`. I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but I just can't seem to track it down.

I've tried to review both servers' IIS settings - both global and site - but I can't find anything that looks different.

I'm currently using in-process session management and not an RDBMS or the like. While various pages on the site *do* require data from a database, that DB server is hosted on the same machine as the IIS instance hosting the pages.

---

### UPDATE #2 (*never mind - I'm an idiot*)

Well, I found the cause of the issue and the problem had nothing to do with my database, session, server, or even code. After I sprinkled a crap-load of logging into the two pages, I found that it all has to do with something that I never imagined would be an issue: Sending email. The delay was caused by one of the lines in that `[...other functional code...]` block in the `netfromaspconn.aspx` that was trying to send me an email because of an error it was encountering. I commented out all references to sending email messages and now everything seems to be working as expected/intended.

The server to which we migrated the site and database is an Azure VM and, [apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity), Microsoft has port 25 hard-blocked for anyone who doesn't do at least $1M in Azure spending annually (*the current minimum requirements to qualify for an Enterprise Agreement*). I admit that I didn't even consider that as a possibility when my MSP recommended the server migration, so I had totally ignored all of that other code in my initial troubleshooting. Of course, the issue was that the sending code is not asynchronous, so it was blocking the rest of the page load until the mail server connection attempt timed out.

Of course, now I have to find a workable solution that will allow my web site to send email messages, but at least I can move forward knowing that the code is "good" (*well, "good enough", at least*). Thank you all for the suggestions and, hopefully, this will help someone else narrow down similar problems on their own servers.

Comment: You don’t encapsulate any of the attributes in quotes, depending on the data stored in the `Session` object this could cause lots of issues. As you are using `Response.Write()` escape literal quotes by doubling them i.e. `<form name=""t""`.

Comment: Thank you, @user692942. I appreciate the suggestion. I've tried "quotifying" all of the attribute values, including those in the `<input />`  tag, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server to manage the session(s)?

It's possible that the new site has a different or much slower connection to the database server.

As a result, then with SQL sessions, then time to "serialize" the data, and save into SQL Server session state management is taking a long time.

I would check and test in web.config, and change session management with "in-proc" sessions to see if this is the issue. Do this as a test, or so called proof of concept.

If using in-proc removes the delay, then that's your issue.

While SQL managed sessions can be rather slow, it not all that noticeable when the SQL Server is on the same web server, or at least you have a very good connection to SQL Server from the web site.

Often in these migrations, you wind up say moving the web site to some cloud server (not on premises any more), however then some VPN was setup to continue to say use SQL Server that is still "on-site" at company location.

This setup will of course cause a vast slow down in SQL Server performance. While most data pulls are rather small, the payload for session state management can become quite large, and put more stress on SQL Server, which in turn with say a VPN connection to SQL server, is a really huge drop in performance.

So, try in-proc session management, and see if that helps.

Unfortunately, in-proc session management while fast, it not all that reliable and robust. You might have to consider moving the current location of the database server as a possible fix here.

Comment: Session management isn't handled by the database, and the DB back-end for the data the pages require is located on the same server as IIS. I've looked through some of the IIS logs and found that the site still seems to be making calls to the old web server for some reason, so that seems like the most likely "culprit" here, but I still have to figure out *why* it's doing that.

Comment: No worry, my post was simple "one" of many things to check. But, I think you really found the issue  -- some stray connection's in code, and they would take about 30+ seconds to "time out" when such connection's fail.